# Importing Maven Project in MuleStudio POM error

Tags: maven-3, mule, mule-studio

I am following the tutorial regarding [Creating a Cloud Connector.](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Your+First+Cloud+Connector)

When importing in MuleStudio, I am getting two errors which I don't completely understand.

`Project build error: Unknown packaging: mule-module`

`Project build error: Unresolveable build extension: Plugin org.mule.tools.devkit:mule-devkit-maven-plugin:3.3.2 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Could not find artifact com.sun:tools:jar:1.6 at specified path C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6/../lib/tools.jar`

I also tried importing the [Mule LDAP Connector](https://github.com/mulesoft/ldap-connector). Same error.

Any ideas to get me out of this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AFAIU, the stacktrace told us as

```
could not be resolved: Could not find artifact 
com.sun:tools:jar:1.6 at specified path 
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6/../lib/tools.jar
```

The **`C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6`** is a `JRE`. We should configure the IDE to use the `JDK` instead. Please note, the file named `tools.jar` is available at `JDK_HOME/lib/tools.jar`

Basically we should set the following environment variable

1. `JAVA_HOME` which points to the JDK installation path, e.g. `C:\java\jdk1.7.0_15`.
2. `PATH` which points to `%JAVA_HOME%/bin`.

Then when we launch any IDE, it will use the configured JDK by default. Anyhow the IDE also allow us the add more/modify JDK via its menus as well.

e.g. for Eclipse

1. Go to `Window` ----> `Preference`
2. Select `Java` ----> `Installed JRE`
3. At the right panel, we can add/modify/remove any JDK.

I hope this may help.

Comment: The check list is good, especially the JAVA_HOME Path setting. I had something forgotten there. Maven in Eclipse did not seem to bother with what is specified in Ecipse / MuleStudio. What I HATE is that I did not specify a path for Maven!!!  and there is not setting to specify it!!!! (Could not find artifact com.sun:tools:jar:1.6 at specified path)

Comment: I could only resolve this by setting `-vm` in `MuleStudio.ini` - See http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini. Check `java.home` in "About MuleStudio" -> "Installation Details". 

A force update was also required after restarting Mule Studio